# Java create menu in another class, add to frame

Tags: java, menuitem, menubar

I try to create a menu in Another class and add it to my frame, but it does not work (nothing adds). Can you help me see what is wrong with the code, thank you.

Class Test:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {                
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();                
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);            
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Class Menu:

```
public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;

    public MenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);            
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menu.add(menuItem);   
    }
}
```

class MenuItem:

```
public class MenuItem extends JMenuItem {

    JMenuItem menuItemUndo;
    JMenuItem menuItemRedo;

    public MenuItem() {
        menuItemUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        menuItemRedo = new JMenuItem("Redo");
    }    
 }
```

Comment: why are you creating new subclasses of `JMenuBar` and `JMenuItem`  when you have not added any functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MenuBar` extends `JMenuBar` and because of that you don't have to create a new `JMenuBar` inside its constructor. This make more sense:

```
public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    JMenu menu;

    public MenuBar() {
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        this.add(menu);            
        .....
    }
}
```

The same thing applies for the `MenuItem` class.

```
public class Undo extends JMenuItem {

    public MenuItem() {
        this.setText("Undo");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
But how do I now add actionListeners to each menuItem?

Comment: The same way you add them to a `JMenuBar` or a `JMenuItem` , more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {                
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();                
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);            
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
 }


class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem menuItemUndo;
    JMenuItem menuItemRedo;

    public MenuBar() {
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuItemUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        menuItemRedo = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        menu.add(menuItemUndo);  
        menu.add(menuItemRedo);
        this.add(menu);   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Run this program. I think it will give you desired output.